# ldapsearch reads cert and lies about it, won't connect as a result

Tags: ssl, openldap, tls

I'm pulling my hair out over ldap playing well with SSL/TLS. I can confirm that the server is listening AND responding on port 636 to SSL request. `openssl s_client -connect freia.fqdn:636 -showcerts` produces expected output, `gnutls-cli-debug -p636 localhost` produces [this](http://pastebin.com/5sCVzQEe). The server has been built from source since the version from ubuntu's repositories had some erronous configs and weren't completing installation. Server is being run with the command `slapd -d -1 -h 'ldap:/// ldaps:///'` Snipped bootup log [here](http://pastebin.com/4jR4beBv). `ldapsearch -H ldap:///` also produces expected output.

```
ldapsearch -H ldaps:///
```

returns

```
ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)

ldapsearch -Z -H ldaps:///
```

returns

```
ldap_start_tls: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
```

The server log says:

```
TLS trace: SSL_accept:before/accept initialization
tls_read: want=11, got=0

TLS: can't accept: (unknown)
```

Since it wasn't being sent anything, i checked what ldapsearch was really sending. It says it can't find the pem file

```
TLS: could not load verify locations (file:`/etc/ssl/private/freia_slapd_key.pem',dir:`').
```

Which is complete nonsense according to `strace ldapsearch -Z -H ldaps:/// -d -1`:

```
open("/etc/ssl/private/freia_slapd_key.pem", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 4
fstat64(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0440, st_size=883, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb770b000
read(4, "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n"..., 4096) = 883
read(4, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(4)                                = 0
munmap(0xb770b000, 4096)                = 0
write(2, "TLS: could not load verify locat"..., 91TLS: could not load verify locations (file:`/etc/ssl/private/freia_slapd_key.pem',dir:`').
```

All certs are readable (or should be)

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1082 2011-12-26 16:50 /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1013 2011-12-26 16:51 /etc/ssl/certs/freia_slapd_cert.pem
-r--r----- 1 root root  883 2011-12-26 16:50 /etc/ssl/private/freia_slapd_key.pem
```

Any ideas at all would be greatly appreciated! Cheers. [Slapd.conf](http://pastebin.com/L839Qfyq) and [ldap.conf](http://pastebin.com/K0z3wLM9)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is in ldap.conf:

```
TLS_CACERT /etc/ssl/private/freia_slapd_key.pem
```

You use the private **key** where you should have used the root **certificate**. In general case, replace it with the proper CA certificate(s) - the certificates that ldapsearch can use as trusted "roots" to confirm all of the other ("untrusted") certificates it meets on the way.

If your /etc/ssl/certs/freia_slapd_**cert**.pem (not /etc/ssl/private/freia_slapd_**key**.pem) is self-signed, it means it is a root for itself and you can/should use it as TLS_CACERT. But it means it would be never trusted by the general public, which uses known "roots" (CAs like Verisign, etc) instead.

By the way, TLS_KEY and TLS_CERT are (rightfully) ignored when placed in your system-wide ldap.conf. See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man5/ldap.conf.5.html

Comment: Made changes accordingly, restarted slapd server, nothing was fixed as far as I could tell :/

Comment: Is ldapsearch still reading *_key.pem instead of *_cert.pem?

Comment: Sigh. Thank you so much. That solved it upon some further inspection.